# Can "be" connect "get"?

Tags: grammar

[*Never Let Me Go*](https://www.studymode.com/essays/Analysis-Kazuo-Ishiguro-s-Never-Let-Me-Go-65251120.html)

> What I want to do now **is get** a few things down about Ruth,

"is get", it seems strange to me.

Comment: *What I want to do now is (run / fight / eat / sleep / walk / read). That's what I want  to do now.* The use of *get down* here is probably used for recording something. (Writing it down.)

Comment: As a side, is it "get things down" or "get things done"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a verb **do** in the clause "What I want to **do** now", so you can omit the infinitive marker **to**.

It is also correct to say:

> What I want to do now is to get things down about Ruth

Comment: You're right that the _do_ is significant, but you do not explain why. I think it is because "do" is a _pro-verb_, that stands for a verb. So the first part presents a template with "to" and a pro-verb, so if you provide a bare verb in the second part ("get") it replaces the pro-verb in the template "to [verb]". If you don't use "do", then there is no template for a bare verb to be slotted into, so "*What I want now is get things down about Ruth" doesn't work.